# Tool to manage requirements throughout a software development lifecycle

Tags: project-management, tools, requirements

I am looking for a tool to manage requirements or features for a software development project. It will be used by a small geographically diverse team of 5-10 people to raise, discuss and track requirements. Consequently it will need:

- Support for multiple users
- Web-based
- Support a hierarchy between requirements, e.g. parent / child relationship
- Provide a means for discussing individual requirements
- Support file uploads
- Cost effective. Ideally free or

Some of the project management tools available are overkill or focus on tasks or resource scheduling rather than features / requirements.

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely go with focusing in **features** / **requirements**.

The tools that I would recommend for this are **[Agile Zen](http://agilezen.com)** and **[Pivotal Tracker](http://pivotaltracker.com)**. They both follow all your requirements except the "Support a hierarchy between requirements" one (or at least not that I know of).

This tools can help you to organize the project's requirements, as well as your development team, who's working with what, how's been your progress so far, what's missing, etc.

I would also recommend to implement *[Scrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28development%29)* in the development / management process. It has certainly helped me a lot during the last couple of years. I would also recommend this books:

- [Ship it!](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/prj/ship-it)
- [Practices of An Agile Developer](http://pragprog.com/titles/pad/practices-of-an-agile-developer)

Good luck with it!

Answer (score 0):

The big boys all use Telelogic's DOORS for requirements management.  There's a reason, and it isn't lemming mentality.

Comment: Some reasons for the downvotes would be nice folks. I have no idea whether the downvote is because DOORS is unsuitable for the requirements, or whether the downvoter thinks it does it badly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use FogBugz to do all of the items you have listed. While it is labeled as a bug tracker, it will do everything you mentioned. You can try it for free and use it for free (up to 2 users). If you need more users, you have to pay but it is relatively cheap ($25 per user per month for the hosted version) Here is a link: http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/

Answer (score -1):

Bugzilla? I know it's a bug tracker per se, but it can do everything you listed above.